# Need help to capture part of string value using particular delimiter function in Vertica

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a `CustomerKey` table which consists of a column `Key` which has sample value like below:

```
ar.system.company.addr.clearinghouse
ar.system.company.addr.dtac.th
ar.system.company.info.clearinghouse.th
.......... ...         ......
ar.system.company.addr.dtac
ar.system.company.addr.paysbuy
```

Now I have to use  one function, which return the value up to the 4th delimiter `.`.

Like:

```
ar.system.company.addr
ar.system.company.addr
..... ... .....
ar.system.company.addr
```

N.B: I have found one similar kind of function `STRTOK()` which is used in Snowflake. But I did not find any function like this in Vertica.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `regexp_substr()`:

```
select regexp_substr(col, '^[^.]+[.][^.]+[.][^.]+[.][^.]+')
```

Comment: Thank you. Its giving expected result

Answer (score 1):

You can also get the substring of the column, from position 1, to the 4th occurrence of '.', starting from position 1 of the string, minus 1.

Like so:

```
WITH
input(string) AS (
          SELECT 'ar.system.company.addr.clearinghouse'
UNION ALL SELECT 'ar.system.company.addr.dtac.th'
UNION ALL SELECT 'ar.system.company.info.clearinghouse.th'
UNION ALL SELECT 'ar.system.company.addr.dtac'
UNION ALL SELECT 'ar.system.company.addr.paysbuy'
)
SELECT
  SUBSTR(string,1,INSTR(string,'.',1,4)-1) AS what_i_need
FROM input;
-- out       what_i_need       
-- out ------------------------
-- out  ar.system.company.addr
-- out  ar.system.company.addr
-- out  ar.system.company.info
-- out  ar.system.company.addr
-- out  ar.system.company.addr
```